# Connecting Postgres database from MySQL Workbench

Tags: postgresql, mysql-workbench

Is there any way to connect to Postgres database using MySQL Workbench? I was hoping it could be easy enough, but didn't find any plugin available.

Comment: "theirs common roots", what common roots?

Comment: You could use Talend, which is an open-source-tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685569/quickstart-database-migration-using-talend

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. That's why it is called ***MySQL*** Workbench. The reason is that the MWB uses a lot of MySQL specific functionality.
I don't think there is currently something similar for Postgres, but you could try Glom or pgadmin3.

A company-independent database manager is the commercial Aqua Data Studio - maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: [pgModeler](https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler) seems to be best free solution but it is written in C++ and requires manual compile step (slow, need to download & configure qt) or paid subscription

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to Check this link: https://data36.com/install-sql-workbench-postgresql/ and after you'll install dependencies/plugins to run Postgres into MWBench

Comment: Welcome to SO. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: This could have been a comment, but as you don't have privileges to comment everywhere, make this answer's context rich by posting a summary of the whole content in the link. I suggest you take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Anyway, we developers value your attempt to support. :)

Comment: The question if for MySQL Workbench, this link is dealing with SQL Workbench

Comment: This is sql-workbench as the question is about mysql workbench.

Comment: This is completely different app without visual scheme editor.

Answer (score 0):

Navicat Premium works for all major Database and apparently the best option if you have Money.
http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html